# Build binary to generate configuration with Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I need to build an executable to test the environment and generate configuration for the following steps of building process. How can I tell Cabal to build such an executable during the configuration stage and not to install it as a part of the distribution?

Comment: You may need to dig down deep. https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#more-complex-packages

Comment: Name your program file `Setup.hs` and set your build type to `Custom`.

Comment: @DanielWagner That would cause dependency resolving not to work if `Setup.hs` depends on some modules not presenting.

Comment: @SherwoodWang Correct. See also gtk2hs, which has a gtk2hs-buildtools package for just this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Modern cabal now has a `setup-depends` field that lets you specify custom dependencies to your setup script (see: http://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-packages.html?highlight=setup-depends#custom-setup-scripts)

As such, your setup script can now use whatever libraries you want to import.